# objects array, order by date

Tags: php, arrays, date

i have an array of objects that I want to sort by the date field, I have tried several examples but I am unable to get it.
I share an image of the array and the code I am trying to use.
Any help is welcome, thank you!

[Array Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kAap.png)

```
        function build_sorter($key) {
            return function ($a, $b) use ($key) {
                return strnatcmp($a[$key], $b[$key]);
            };
        }
        $NuevoArrayPedidos= usort($ArrayPedidos, $this->build_sorter('fecha'));

        return $NuevoArrayPedidos;
```

ERROR: Warning: usort() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given in /home/vestatex/gestionWebs.vestatex.es/controllers/pedidosController.php on line 82 (USORT LINE)

Comment: Their date is in an XML object and that in turn is in a private object structure of a class.
Please do not show any pictures. Display PHP code with sample data.
Unless you are displaying reproducible code, the question remains a mystery.

Comment: The error is pretty clear - what you're supplying is *not an array*, but an object. And your dump confirms it. Check the object for any methods that might return its contents as an actual array.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can help you 
I convert the time to the int and then compare it 
And you `['fecha'][0]` for getting the time

```php
function date_compare($a, $b)
{
    $t1 = strtotime($a['fecha'][0]);
    $t2 = strtotime($b['fecha'][0]);
    return $t1 - $t2;
}
    
$NuevoArrayPedidos = usort($ArrayPedidos, 'date_compare');
return $NuevoArrayPedidos;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I get this error;

Warning: usort() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given in /home/vestatex/gestionWebs.vestatex.es/controllers/pedidosController.php on line 301

The array I pass is an array of objects
[

$pedidoTemp = new pedidos($resourceId,$resourceRef,$importeTotal,"Vestatex",$nombreCliente, 

$resourceIdCarro, $direccionCliente, $resourceIdEstado, $resourceFormaPago, 

$resourceFecha,$ArrayProductos, $resourceCarrier, $gastoEnvio);

$ArrayPedidos->append($pedidoTemp);

]